# problem with export action with pageSize in dataProvider

Tags: pagination, yii2, grid, export

this is my dataProvider in my Controller:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['NumeroInElenco' => SORT_ASC]],
            'pagination' => [
              'pageSize' => 10,
                ],
            ]);
        

        $this->load($params);
```

Now I can visualize 10records in my grid, and this is good. But there is a problem, when I activate the button toggle data (to show all records and not only the firts 10), if I export the data the excel file returns me only the firts 10. I think that the reason is the pageSize declaration. How I can fix this problem??
I hope to be clear, I have to solve it quickly.

Comment: How do you show more rows in gridview? Show you code where you export data.

Comment: Set `$dataProvider->pagination = false` before export to get all records

Comment: Thank you, pagination = false is the solution !

Comment: @InsaneSkull What about posting an answer :) so that this question on SE has an accepted answer and not left blank?

Comment: @ShamsM.Monem sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Pagination to false to get all records in export.

```
$dataProvider->pagination = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $product = Product::find()->where(['show' => 1]);
        $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $product->count()]);
        $pages->pageSize = 3;
        $pages->pageSizeParam = false;
        $model=$product->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();

    return $this->render('index', ['product' => $model, 'page' => $pages]);
}
```